# My written job offer was given to someone else

Tags: job-offer

Greetings and Salutations.

I was given a WRITTEN JOB OFFER LETTER in May, I signed it and was awaiting government clearance to get a start date. The clearance finally was completed today (Sept 26), but then I was told that the job was no longer available because it was given to someone else. Somebody dropped the ball.

Has anyone ever experienced this before? If so, how did you go about the situation?

Comment: Legal questions are off topic.  They are also highly dependent on jurisdiction.  If you are solely interested in legality, you could try posting this over on law.stackexchange while being specific about where you are.

Comment: Even if you could get legal redress. it would.likely take months or even years and cost you more than the job might be worth. Move on.

Comment: As Joe says it depends on your legal system - you could sue for breach of contract

Comment: legal question. You have a signed contract that other part don´t respected it is 100% scam.

Comment: We have no evidence that the "signed contract" has no firm exit clause in the case of extended delays non-attributable to the hiring company - a 4 month delay to receive "government clearance" (I'm guessing ... security clearances?) might not be the norm, and thus the hiring company utilised its exit clause to hire someone else quicker?

Answer (score 3):

This is an anecdote as you ask has anyone been in this situation before, it is  not legal advice...

I had a similar situation, a job offer accepted and signed and then withdrawn before the start date (company decided to switch technologies). This was after I'd resigned from my previous job. Not a great situation to be in.

The company was apologetic. Initially that was all. I had to push a bit and point out that it wasn't just a formal offer they were withdrawing but an actual contract to start work that they were changing.

In the end I got paid for the minimum amount they could have paid me for. As if I had started work and immediately been given notice of termination. I think the contract was a week's notice. Which was not much, but was better than nothing.

Again as many people have said, get Legal advice if you want to pursue. What happened to me was specific to my jurisdiction and the contract that I had.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/49352)

Comment: It is difficult to answer the question without giving legal advice. I was giving an example of what *could* happen based on experience.

Comment: @JeremyFrench which again isnt an answer post it as a comment next time....

Comment: @Raoul Mensink the question states "Has anyone ever experienced this before? If so, how did you go about the situation?" how is it not answering that?

Comment: @JeremyFrench First this has no value at all, also it gives no Information how you got about it. You just wrote down what happened. NOT what you did about it. Then at the end you throw in an Assumtion. An answer would have been: blablabla this happened with me which is sorta similar. I did this after doing that. in the end blablabla. I think you can do abc to try and get more Information, but as is I would move on if i were you

Comment: Have cleared it up a bit in line with your suggestions. The OP is in a bad situation, if it is possible to help or at least explain what could happen for them it is worth doing.

Comment: This gives some value to the OP while not giving legal advice. I think that's great.

Comment: Interesting expirience. :)